# How can I best browse without using my hands?

Tags: google-chrome, web, accessibility

I have my hands full most of the day although I can do some operations on a computer. I am wondering how can I best browse (read articles/view videos/reply to emails/browsing tabs) without using my hands? I mostly use Chrome but would be open to use a different browser.

Comment: Do you have a microphone?

Comment: @Burgi Yes the one in my laptop but could add an external one

Comment: Lenovo Ideapad Y series

Comment: Could you be more specific about, if not your hands, what you want to browse with? Would a script that slowly scrolls through webpages work? Or do you want to use foot pedals/joystick/cellphone?

Comment: If you are a windows user, your best option may be [Autohotkey](https://autohotkey.com)

Comment: @NonlinearFruit Yes, anything BUT hands is possible and a scrolling script could work

Comment: [Mycroft AI](https://github.com/MycroftAI/mycroft-core/tree/master/mycroft/skills) could solve this problem with voice commands. With the bonus of being support easy to install on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Browse the Internet with Buckets of Water

> Yes, anything BUT hands is possible and a scrolling script could work

This is a Windows solution that utilizes [Autohotkey](https://autohotkey.com/) and [this](http://www.instructables.com/id/Makey-Makey-Water-Piano/) instructable for setting up a [Makey Makey](http://www.makeymakey.com/). Note, you can use Makey Makey with something less messy than buckets of water, in fact you can use [a](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/b3/37/9e/b3379ea63daae05bb60c9009c93b088a.jpg)[n](http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5315/7167028594_ac22abb62f_n.jpg)[y](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/9b/c7/d5/9bc7d5bccb4ab4ad995d2db17f5f218c.jpg)[t](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/1m2iQ4fws8Y/hqdefault.jpg)[h](http://madartlab.com/files/2013/02/makey-cat-photo-booth.png)[i](https://www.eduporium.com/sites/default/files/BananaPiano.jpg)[n](http://makezine.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/ddr-mm.png)[g](https://c1.staticflickr.com/3/2836/11318053393_0fa9d44bcb_b.jpg)! Also, a non-Makey Makey device (eg foot pedals, keyboard Rube Goldberg [machine](http://www.bv.k12.oh.us/GalleryImages/201552721135259_image.JPG)) would work as long as it pressed the physical keys on the keyboard or triggered the key events for the particular keys we are mapping (<kbd>Up</kbd>, <kbd>Down</kbd>, <kbd>Left</kbd>, <kbd>Right</kbd> in this case). This solution should work with any default browser and could be modified to auto-scroll.

### Setup

- **Install** [AutohotKey](https://autohotkey.com/)
- **Setup** [Makey Makey](http://www.makeymakey.com/) by following [this](http://www.instructables.com/id/Makey-Makey-Water-Piano/) Instructable

  - Alternatively: setup some other input device
  - Map one bucket (or whatever you are using) to:
  - <kbd>Up</kbd> - for scroll up
  - <kbd>Down</kbd> - for scroll down
  - <kbd>Left</kbd> - for previous site
  - <kbd>Right</kbd> - for next site
- **Save** the code posted here to some *filename.ahk*
- **Modify** the code

  - Add desired URLs
  - Change scroll speed
  - Change hotkey mapping
  - Add functionality for starting/stopping videos
  - Add functionality for choosing webpage to browse
- **Open** *filename.ahk* with the Autohotkey.exe

  - When you trigger the first webpage, it will open the default browser and you may have to maximize the browser
  - Also make sure the mouse is positioned about the webpage so that scrolling works
- **Enjoy** your new setup!

  - Memorize which bucket maps to which key
  - Note that you are 'completing' the circuit, so keep one foot on the bar when placing the other in the bucket
  - For best results, use bare feet

**AutoHotkey (AHK) Code**

```ahk
;Dont Change
i:=0

;Do Change - Add as many SitesX as needed
Sites0:="http://www.gmail.com"
Sites1:="http://superuser.com/q/1070420/468052"
Sites2:="https://autohotkey.comm"

;Update to Equal Number of Sites
NumSites:=3

;===============================================;

RIGHT::
    i:=Mod(i+1, NumSites)
    Run, % Sites%i%
    Return

LEFT::
    i:=Mod(i-1+NumSites, NumSites)
    Run, % Sites%i%
    Return

UP::Send {WheelUp}

DOWN::Send {WheelDown}
```

**Makey Makey board**
[image: Makey Makey Board]

**The Makey Makey setup from Instructables**
[image: Makey Makey Setup]

### Tear Down

To end the hotkey script:

- Find the AHK icon on the taskbar
- Right click it
- Click `Exit`

[image: Exit Hotkey Script]

### Warning

I do not recommended this particular setup if:

- Floor is not water resistant
- You carry sharp/electronic/breakable items
- You're hydrophobic
- You don't enjoy having fun

**[NOTE:** I am not liable for what you do with this knowledge and that includes water damage XD **]**

**[NOTE:** Makey Makey is a serious possibility, especially if you replace the water buckets with cardboard wrapped in aluminium foil **]**

**[NOTE:** I verified this on Windows 7 with Chrome and without the water **]**

Comment: Some how I don't think this is what the OP was after but.... wow!

Comment: Haha....Shoes off, jeans pulled up knee high...I can't imagine myself getting ready for some internet surfing with buckets of water. And what if this was the only option available to all ?

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like I do admit that buckets of water might be a little too eccentric for most people. I used it as an example for novelty's sake. `Makey Makey` + `AHK` is pretty potent for use cases like this. That is why I included the note at the end about using cardboard with foil instead of buckets with water.

Comment: @NonlinearFruit Understand your point. After reading your post I went ahead and done my own research. Found [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I0HpZRQkths), and thinking of making something for myself

Comment: That's awesome! I know about the Makey Makey but have never tried it. I wouldn't buy one but if I had one, I would totally implement this (not with buckets of water though) :-)

Answer (score 2):

Foot pedals!

There's one and three pedal types and here's a typical example of one

[image: enter link description here]

These things are programmable - here's an [example of one being used as a vim controller](https://github.com/alevchuk/vim-clutch), and it seems they can be programmed to emulate strings. Tie it in with AHK, and you might be able to use combinations of foot pedals as a chording keyboard type setup.

Another idea might be to have more than one and do as [Tom Scott](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lIFE7h3m40U&feature=youtu.be) did with  his emoji keyboards - apparently he used lua macros (to tie key combinations to keys on a specific keyboard) and AHK to do this. I'll leave it as an exercise to the reader to how many buttons he'd need for a minimal chording keyboard and emulated mouse setup, and the exact AHK magic.

Also, does not involve buckets of water, which is a plus.

Comment: Haha, not having buckets of water is a plus?

Comment: In some cases, yes. I'd admit to upvoting your answer  for the sheer level of lateral thinking tho.